# Reasoning about an arbitrary transformation function based on observed data

Tags: distributions, probability, data-transformation

I have two lots of data that have been independently, arbitrarily transformed from the same original data source using the same permutation algorithm. I would like to know what kind of statements I can make about the original data source or the transformation process by comparing these two data sets. All the data are non-negative integers.

To express this in R code:

```
# These true values and permutation function are unknown/unobservable
set.seed(1904)
true.xs <- round(rnorm(1000, mean=100, sd=15), 0)
unknown.trans <- function(orig)orig + round(rnorm(length(orig), sd=3),0)

# These observations have been made
xs.1 <- unknown.trans(true.xs)
xs.2 <- unknown.trans(true.xs)
```

I would like to know what I can say about `true.xs` or `unknown.trans` given `xs.1` and `xs.2`. I'm willing to make some fairly strong assumptions if that will help (i.e. that the transformation function is symetrical around zero, etc.).

Comment: Are you talking about permutations here, or about some other transformation of data? If you mean permutations, then your R code seems to be incorrect, because sum(true.xs == 96) is 29, and sum(xs.1 == 96) is 23.

Comment: Apologies, just some arbitrary transformation of the data. The permutation is used incorrectly in the original problem domain, but I'll change that now.